# Calculating the frequency of CPM signal in System Generator

Tags: fpga, digital-communications, frequency-measurement, xilinx-system-generator, digital-modulation

I have a circuit which has been designed by System Generator to be implemented on FPGA. The circuit's output is a CPM (Continuous Phase Modulation) signal in which it is apparent that its instantaneous frequency is changeable. I should transmit the data via UART and RS232 to see it on a computer.

However, it has the problem that, in high frequencies, the Nyquist criterion has been violated and hence in high frequency I have not a nice sinusoidal signal. I think that for resolving this issue **I should relate the start of UART to the frequency of output signal**. Now I wonder:

- **How should I measure the instantaneous frequency of CPM signal?**
- In other words, **how should I measure it in System Generator?**

Comment: "CPM"? short for ...

Comment: @jippie Continuous Phase Modulation